# Нужен код "рычажной" функции C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Вкратце - есть getasynckeystate(кнопка), но, функция выполняется только если эта кнопка нажата, и если ее отпустить -- функция не будет работать.
Нужно - нажать кнопку 1 раз, и чтобы функция выполнялась пока я не нажму второй раз эту же кнопку

Comment: вам нужно где-то хранить состояние функции, это может быть статическая переменная, глобальная переменная или подобное.

Comment: На таймер повесить проверку переменной, и обрабатывать "нажатие"